# Python, Openpyxl, search Excel column for substring, add to another column

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I have three columns in an excel spreadsheet. I'm trying to accomplish my goal with Openpyxl 2.4.7, Excel 2016, and Pycharm 2016.3.2.

```
|    Type    |             Name            |            Fits            |             Column D              |
|------------|-----------------------------|----------------------------|-----------------------------------|
| Universal  | Product A: Universal Fit    |                            | Blank                             |
| Automation | Product B: Chevrolet, Ford  | Chevrolet, GMC, Cadillac   | Chevrolet, Ford, GMC, Cadillac    |
| Automation | Product C: Chevrolet, Honda | Chevrolet, Cadillac, Honda | Chevrolet, Honda, Cadillac, Honda |
| Universal  | Product D: Universal Fit    |                            | Blank                             |
```

I'm trying to search the "Name" and "Fits" columns for car names, and then add them to Column D but I'm totally at a loss. I have been trying:

```
import openpyxl, pprint
print('Opening workbook...')
wb=openpyxl.load_workbook('updatedSheet.xlsx')
sheet = wb.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet1')

COLUMN_D_DICT={'Chevrolet':'Chevrolet','GM':'GMC', 'Cadillac':'Cadillac', 'Honda':'Honda'}

maxRow = sheet.max_row + 1
for rowNum in range(2, maxRow):
    name= sheet.cell(row=rowNum, column=2).value
    type = sheet.cell(row=rowNum, column=1).value
    if type == "Automation":
        if name in COLUMN_D_DICT:
            sheet.cell(row=rowNum, column=8).value = PLATFORM_UPDATES[name]
        else:
            sheet.cell(row=rowNum, column=8).value = ""
    else:
        sheet.cell(row=rowNum, column=8).value = ""
```

Super new to python so just trying to work through step by step, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following example:

```
# Use a set() for your Keywords
COLUMN_D_SET = set(['Chevrolet','GMC', 'Cadillac', 'Honda'])

maxRow = sheet.max_row + 1
for rowNum in range(1, maxRow):
    type = sheet.cell(row=rowNum, column=1).value
    # Concat Values from Column Name and Fits
    name= sheet.cell(row=rowNum, column=2).value
    name = name+' '+sheet.cell(row=rowNum, column=3).value

    # Define a empty list for the Column D Result
    value_D = []
    if type == "Automation":
        # Split by Blank
        for word1 in name.split(' '):
            # Split by ','
            for word in word1.split(','):
                # Match if word in Set of Keywords 
                # and not already in list of value_D
                if word in COLUMN_D_SET and not word in value_D:
                    value_D.append(word)

    # Assing the aggreated list of words or a Empty list to Column D
    sheet.cell(row=rowNum, column=4).value = ', '.join(value_D)
```

***Tested with Python: 3.4.2***